# How to fetch values of data from different class in json? e.g name using its id

Tags: c#, json, api, class

I am currently making a flight search app in c#. I am binding the json into a datagridview.Here is my code so far.

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/GB/GBP/en-GB/UK-sky/JFK-sky/2021-09-01?inboundpartialdate=2021-09-10");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "d6deba1f4bmsh21094fa230617cdp180268jsn452ac752d55a");
            request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Application>(response.Content);

            DataTable table = new DataTable();


            string quoteID;
            string strPrice;
            string Destination;
            string Origin;
            string Carrier;
            string Dates;
            foreach (var a in results.Quotes)
            {
                
                quoteID = String.Format("{0}", a.QuoteId);
                Debug.WriteLine(quoteID);
                strPrice = String.Format("{0:C}", a.MinPrice);
                Debug.WriteLine(strPrice);
                Destination = String.Format("{0}", a.OutboundLeg.DestinationId);
                Debug.WriteLine("" + Destination);
                Origin = String.Format("{0}", a.OutboundLeg.OriginId);
                Debug.WriteLine("" + Origin);
                Carrier = String.Format("{0}", a.OutboundLeg.CarrierIds[0]);
                Debug.WriteLine("" + Carrier);
                DateTime Date = a.OutboundLeg.DepartureDate;
                Dates = Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                Debug.WriteLine("" + Dates);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
                                 quoteID,
                                 strPrice,
                                 Carrier,
                                 Destination,
                                 Origin,
                                 Dates);



            }
```

Here is my json.

```
{
  "Quotes" : [ {
    "QuoteId" : 1,
    "MinPrice" : 185,
    "Direct" : false,
    "OutboundLeg" : {
      "CarrierIds" : [ 1247 ],
      "OriginId" : 65655,
      "DestinationId" : 60987,
      "DepartureDate" : "2021-09-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "QuoteDateTime" : "2021-03-17T09:31:00"
  }, {
    "QuoteId" : 2,
    "MinPrice" : 310,
    "Direct" : false,
    "OutboundLeg" : {
      "CarrierIds" : [ 50441 ],
      "OriginId" : 43139,
      "DestinationId" : 60987,
      "DepartureDate" : "2021-09-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "QuoteDateTime" : "2021-03-16T20:39:00"
  }, {
    "QuoteId" : 3,
    "MinPrice" : 561,
    "Direct" : false,
    "OutboundLeg" : {
      "CarrierIds" : [ 1033 ],
      "OriginId" : 54353,
      "DestinationId" : 60987,
      "DepartureDate" : "2021-09-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "QuoteDateTime" : "2021-03-16T15:34:00"
  }, {
    "QuoteId" : 4,
    "MinPrice" : 806,
    "Direct" : false,
    "OutboundLeg" : {
      "CarrierIds" : [ 1033 ],
      "OriginId" : 67662,
      "DestinationId" : 60987,
      "DepartureDate" : "2021-09-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "QuoteDateTime" : "2021-03-16T21:47:00"
  }, {
    "QuoteId" : 5,
    "MinPrice" : 883,
    "Direct" : true,
    "OutboundLeg" : {
      "CarrierIds" : [ 1618 ],
      "OriginId" : 65698,
      "DestinationId" : 60987,
      "DepartureDate" : "2021-09-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "QuoteDateTime" : "2021-03-16T15:15:00"
  }, {
    "QuoteId" : 6,
    "MinPrice" : 2137,
    "Direct" : true,
    "OutboundLeg" : {
      "CarrierIds" : [ 1859 ],
      "OriginId" : 67662,
      "DestinationId" : 60987,
      "DepartureDate" : "2021-09-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "QuoteDateTime" : "2021-03-16T21:47:00"
  } ],
  "Carriers" : [ {
    "CarrierId" : 1033,
    "Name" : "Aer Lingus"
  }, {
    "CarrierId" : 1859,
    "Name" : "Virgin Atlantic"
  }, {
    "CarrierId" : 1618,
    "Name" : "Qatar Airways"
  }, {
    "CarrierId" : 50441,
    "Name" : "easyJet"
  }, {
    "CarrierId" : 1247,
    "Name" : "LEVEL"
  } ],
  "Places" : [ {
    "Name" : "Aberdeen",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 40074,
    "IataCode" : "ABZ",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "ABZ",
    "CityName" : "Aberdeen",
    "CityId" : "ABER",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Belfast City",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 42644,
    "IataCode" : "BHD",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "BHD",
    "CityName" : "Belfast",
    "CityId" : "BELF",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Birmingham",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 42664,
    "IataCode" : "BHX",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "BHX",
    "CityName" : "Birmingham",
    "CityId" : "BIRM",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Bristol",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 43139,
    "IataCode" : "BRS",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "BRS",
    "CityName" : "Bristol",
    "CityId" : "BRIS",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Cardiff",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 45676,
    "IataCode" : "CWL",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "CWL",
    "CityName" : "Cardiff",
    "CityId" : "CARD",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Edinburgh",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 49369,
    "IataCode" : "EDI",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "EDI",
    "CityName" : "Edinburgh",
    "CityId" : "EDIN",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Glasgow International",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 54353,
    "IataCode" : "GLA",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "GLA",
    "CityName" : "Glasgow",
    "CityId" : "GLAS",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Humberside",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 57113,
    "IataCode" : "HUY",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "HUY",
    "CityName" : "Kirmington",
    "CityId" : "HUMB",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Inverness",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 59078,
    "IataCode" : "INV",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "INV",
    "CityName" : "Inverness",
    "CityId" : "INVE",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Ronaldsway",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 59117,
    "IataCode" : "IOM",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "IOM",
    "CityName" : "Castletown",
    "CityId" : "CAST",
    "CountryName" : "Isle of Man"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Jersey",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 60946,
    "IataCode" : "JER",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "JER",
    "CityName" : "Jersey",
    "CityId" : "JERS",
    "CountryName" : "Jersey"
  }, {
    "Name" : "New York John F. Kennedy",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 60987,
    "IataCode" : "JFK",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "JFK",
    "CityName" : "New York",
    "CityId" : "NYCA",
    "CountryName" : "United States"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Leeds Bradford",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 65393,
    "IataCode" : "LBA",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "LBA",
    "CityName" : "Leeds",
    "CityId" : "LEED",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "London City",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 65465,
    "IataCode" : "LCY",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "LCY",
    "CityName" : "London",
    "CityId" : "LOND",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "London Gatwick",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 65655,
    "IataCode" : "LGW",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "LGW",
    "CityName" : "London",
    "CityId" : "LOND",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "London Heathrow",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 65698,
    "IataCode" : "LHR",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "LHR",
    "CityName" : "London",
    "CityId" : "LOND",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "London Luton",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 66270,
    "IataCode" : "LTN",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "LTN",
    "CityName" : "London",
    "CityId" : "LOND",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Manchester",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 67662,
    "IataCode" : "MAN",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "MAN",
    "CityName" : "Manchester",
    "CityId" : "MANC",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Teesside International",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 68229,
    "IataCode" : "MME",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "MME",
    "CityName" : "Durham",
    "CityId" : "MMEA",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Newcastle",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 70060,
    "IataCode" : "NCL",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "NCL",
    "CityName" : "Newcastle",
    "CityId" : "NEWC",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Newquay",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 70745,
    "IataCode" : "NQY",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "NQY",
    "CityName" : "Newquay",
    "CityId" : "NEWQ",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Norwich",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 71017,
    "IataCode" : "NWI",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "NWI",
    "CityName" : "Norwich",
    "CityId" : "NORW",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "Southampton",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 82165,
    "IataCode" : "SOU",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "SOU",
    "CityName" : "Southampton",
    "CityId" : "SOUT",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Name" : "London Stansted",
    "Type" : "Station",
    "PlaceId" : 82398,
    "IataCode" : "STN",
    "SkyscannerCode" : "STN",
    "CityName" : "London",
    "CityId" : "LOND",
    "CountryName" : "United Kingdom"
  } ],
  "Currencies" : [ {
    "Code" : "USD",
    "Symbol" : "$",
    "ThousandsSeparator" : ",",
    "DecimalSeparator" : ".",
    "SymbolOnLeft" : true,
    "SpaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol" : false,
    "RoundingCoefficient" : 0,
    "DecimalDigits" : 2
  } ]
}
```

The issue that i have rn is that i am trying to fetch the names of the carrier and cities using the ID given to me in the outboundleg class. For example if i had the ID 1247 i want to get the value "LEVEL" which is in the Carriers class. WHat sort of code would i need in order to reach the value in the other class. So far as you can see in my code i can get the id numbers for each quote my goal is to print out the names in the datagridview rather than the numbers.

EDITED CODE

```
  foreach (var quote in quotesResponse.Quotes)
            {

                var carrierInfo = carriersResponse.Carriers
                                             .Where(x => quote.OutboundLeg.CarrierIds.Contains(x.CarrierId))
                                             .Select(x => x.Name);

                var destinationInfo = destinationResponse.Places.FirstOrDefault(item => quote.OutboundLeg.DestinationIds == item.PlaceId);
                strPrice = String.Format("{0:C}", quote.MinPrice);
                Debug.WriteLine(strPrice);
                DateTime Date = quote.OutboundLeg.DepartureDate;
                Dates = Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                Debug.WriteLine("" + Dates);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
                                 quote.QuoteId,
                                 strPrice,
                                 string.Join(", ", carrierInfo),
                                 destinationInfo.Name,
                                 quote.OutboundLeg.OriginId,
                                 Dates);

            }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far and where did you stuck?

Comment: So far i have managed to show the ids in numbers but i dont know how to show the names for the id's @PeterCsala

Comment: [ask], and [mre]. while we have 2 invalid/incomplete json  Json document, and the expected output is clear. We don't have any code. We don't know if you fail to Deserialize the Json or filtering it. Or if you didn't serialize and you are navigating using xpath/Jobject etc.

Comment: @Self i have made some edits to the question hope it helps in solving my problem

Comment: Started writting with the imcomplete information, so I will only comment. But first we need to have **the talk**: `dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Application>`. This is not nice. The first paragraph of the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic#) is clear. That a "Im too lazy to write a class that match my input". The only time it's not "free coffe for everyone" offense is when you work with "_a COM API, from a dynamic language such as IronPython, [..]_".

Comment: And the `DataTable` a line after is just the proof of that. Slap your Json into https://app.quicktype.io/ choose C# language in the top right corner box. And get your class declaration for the cost of one copy-past.. So here is a simple interpretation of the 1rst version of your question https://dotnetfiddle.net/yDift1 . Lines ~23 is where you will find the Where SubList.Contains filter.

Comment: ok ill make some edits with the code thanks for the help @Self

Comment: @Self How would i do this same method for the destinationId since thats not a list

Comment: That a simple Where == .. ?

Comment: Ok so Where, filter a list and give you a list, right. And there you don't want a list as result cause you know there is only one result. So you can use .FirstOrDefault instead of Where. That will give you one object instead of a collection. So you won't need the select neither.

Comment: I have done that but when i run the program i am getting [Holiday_Test.Form1+Place,System.String] rather than the name. I have attached my edited code above

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wK3tfV , Here is a short example because `Where` give you a list even if there is only one item. because that what `Where` does

Comment: Ho and with first or default you get the object instead of a collection of object. You can navigate using property `destinationInfo.Name`, `destinationInfo.Type` etc

Comment: @Self your help has been amazing , i used your example however im getting a blank response which im guessing its becasue of the Name = " " but what would i make that equal to

Comment: that last edit make no sense.. `var listOfDestinations = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Select(x => new Place { PlaceId = x, Name = ""}).ToList();` .. I use that to generate random cat for the sake of the example. I starting to doubt my explanation. You should use something like `var destinationInfo = destinationResponse.Places.FirstOrDefault(item => quote.OutboundLeg.DestinationIds == item.PlaceId);`

Comment: thank you managed to get it working

Comment: im sorry this is my first time using these commands. Your help been amazing @Self

Comment: those are called LinQ. I advice reading the description of the methode in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-5.0. Just one per block there is a lot of repetition. But just to plant the seed of "Ho there is a method that will count the number of element that satisfy a condition". AS msdn tutorial is not great on the subject I will advice for YT tutorial like Tim Corey https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yClSNQdVD7g .